# Why is this map returning an rvalue?

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I am using the library [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and wish to create an `unordered_map` of `std::string` to `nlohmann::json`.

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

class basic_container {
public:
    using key_type = std::string;
    using mapped_type = nlohmann::json;
    using container_type = std::unordered_map<key_type, mapped_type>;
    using reference = typename container_type::reference;
    using const_reference = typename container_type::const_reference;

    // error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue
    reference at(const key_type &key) {
        return data.at(key);
    }

    // warning: returning reference to temporary
    const_reference at(const key_type &key) const {
        return data.at(key);
    }

    // error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue
    reference operator[](const key_type &key) {
        return data[key];
    }

private:
    container_type data;
};
```

The `nlohmann::json` class is defined in the library similarly to the following.

```
template<...>
class basic_json {};

using json = basic_json<>;
```

I can't figure out why I'm having problems when trying to return a `reference` or a `const reference` to a `nlohmann::json`. The full compiler error for the `error:` sections within the above code is outlined below.

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'container::reference' {aka 'std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::basic_json<> >&'} to an rvalue of type 'std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, nlohmann::basic_json<> >'
```

The nicer intellisense error.

```
a reference of type "container::reference" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::string, bool, int64_t, uint64_t, double, std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer, std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>>"
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Edit: The solution was to properly define the aliases. See the following.

```
class basic_container {
public:
    using key_type = std::string;
    using mapped_type = nlohmann::json;
    using container_type = std::unordered_map<key_type, mapped_type>;
    // using reference = typename container_type::reference;
    // using const_reference = typename container_type::const_reference;
    using reference = typename mapped_type::reference;
    using const_reference = typename mapped_type::const_reference;

    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your wrappers for `at()`, et. al. are returning the wrong thing.

If you look up the [reference for unordered_map::at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/at): it returns a reference to a (const) `T`, a.k.a. `value_type`, a.k.a. your `mapped_type`.

`reference`/`const_reference` is something completely different.

The same problem also happens with your `operator[]` overload.

P.S. The easiest way to avoid this confusion is to declare your return types as (const-qualified, where appropriate) `auto &` (in this case). Let your C++ compiler get it right.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how they are returning the wrong thing. If you look at the `nlohmann::basic_json` code, it defines `reference` as `basic_json &` and `const basic_json &`. I have provided a `reference alias` for `nlohmann::basic_json::reference`. In other words, `reference` =` basic_json &`. How is this incorrect?

Comment: You are correct. I somehow missed that. Appreciate the answer

Comment: What `basic_json` defines as `reference` is irrelevant. You are defining reference as `using reference = typename container_type::reference;`, you are aliasing `unordered_map`'s definitions, not `basic_json`'s. `basic_json`'s definitions are irrelevant, you are calling unordered_map's methods, and are returning what they return.